# Can't connect remotely to database on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am new to managing servers but I have just been given full access to set up an MS SQL Database on win server 2003. I have created a Database successfully and can connect locally (via remote desktop server)

Problem is I can't connect to the database from my personal computer (remotely, via ms sql server management studio). I have followed several tutorials such as: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

The error I am receiving is:

> Cannot connect to 'servername'
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 53)

Any help will be great, thanks!

Comment: Serverfault.com I'd say - but try opening up port 1433 TCP on the remote pc

Comment: `Named Pipes Provider` - for a remote connection????

Comment: Do you have "Allow Remote Connections to this Server" checked in the MSSQL server options?

Comment: PostMan, how do you open port 1433 on the server?.. sorry. Win firewall is disabled (if thats what you mean)

Will A, yes it is checked.

Comment: Um, that depends on the computer I guess. But I know that's the port MS SQL Runs on by default

Answer (score 0):

"SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections"

You need to enable remote tcp/ip connections in sql surface area configuration. It's new in 2005 and then dropped in 2008.

If that doesn't work, you either have a network issue are are perhaps giving the wrong name - maybe you installed a named instance?